# sustituir un valor de un dataframe ubicandolo con su indice iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hola quiero sustituir un valor de un dataframe usando su indice algo asi:

```
df.iloc[1,1].value = 'nuevo valor'
```

entiendo que asi no es pero no se como hacerlo correctamente

Comment: Probaste haciendo df.iloc[...] = ...?

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien puedes hacer uso de iloc que ya por si solo trae el valor de la celda y solo asignar el nuevo valor

```
import pandas as pd

# Creamos un data frame de ejemplo
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Columna A': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'Columna B': ['d', 'e', 'f']
})

#  Utilizamos iloc para asignar un nuevo valor a la celda
# En este caso es la fila con el indice 1 en la primera columna que seria 'Columna A'
df.iloc[1, 0] = 'nuevo valor'

# Imprimir el DataFrame modificado
print("\nDataFrame modificado:")
print(df)


DataFrame modificado:
     Columna A Columna B
0            a         d
1  nuevo valor         e
2            c         f
```